# ReSharper permanent license

Tags: resharper

My company has a set of licenses for ReSharper 8.1 which are managed by our own ReSharper license server that exists inside our domain. Most developers just acquire a floating license as an when needed, however I live and work remotely so have acquired a permanent license.

This all works perfectly, except anytime I connect to our VPN (thereby putting me inside the domain), every VS install I have open, continuously pops up with the *License Information* dialog, prompting me to do something (what it wants me to do, I'm not sure).

[image]

If I click *OK* is just pops up again, <s>likewise if I click *Cancel*</s> (Actually I just checked this again and clicking *Cancel* dismisses the dialog but also removes ReSharper from the current VS instannce, i.e. as if I don't have a license). Obviously I don't want to release my license, so I'm confused as to what it wants me to do.

Anyone else have this same issue and know how to resolve it?

Comment: Have you considered asking Jetbrains instead? They're usually quite quick to respond to support queries.

Comment: You say you usually use a floating license, but this dialog seems to be detailing a permanent license.  Is that permanent license in use by someone else at the same time?

Comment: So I personally have and use a permanent license, but others in my company (who work from the office) use floating licenses.

Comment: Did you try this article http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/38938733-Permanent-License-Keys-issues-with-ReSharper-8-x-and-License-Server?

Comment: Thanks @Alexander that appears to have solved the issue. If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, the [following article](http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/38938733-Permanent-License-Keys-issues-with-ReSharper-8-x-and-License-Server) may help in such cases:

> There are several known issues with ReSharper 8.x, where the Permanent
>   License key cannot be used on the client PC as intended.
>
> To workaround the issue, please:
>
> - Close all VS with R# instances
> - Open regedit
> - Proceed to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JetBrains\ReSharper
> - There you will see all kinds of different nodes for each ReSharper version and its VS versions
> - Expand all nodes there, and remove all 'LicenseSettings' nodes in all available places. If you have more 'LicenseSettings' nodes on your
>     PC, please remove them as well.
>
> Doing this will fully erase your License Information data and prevent
>   ReSharper to export previous License Info (from earlier versions),
>   which is done after normal upgrade. So, you License Information dialog
>   will be reset to default values and you can re-enter and re-obtain the
>   key from the LS.
>
> Also, please double-check that there's no Permanent Ticket left on the
>   License Server after that. If it's there, it should be revoked
>   manually by the LS Administrator; as well as make sure that you are
>   using the latest build of JetBrains License Server available.